# Is there a way to route some message for virtual domain via smtp transport in Postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

I have some mailboxes on *domain.com*, linked to Google Workspace account. It works fine, but I need in some mailboxes with basic functionality (to send/to receive messages only), without Google Workspace functionality, without payments to Google Workspace for these accounts, and they should be in *domain.com* too.

There is such functionality in Google Workspace, it can transport mail for unexisting adresses to specified server address. I've created server with Postfix, Dovecot and Roundcube. Postfix recieves message from Google Workspace, send them through **virtual_mailbox_domains**, **virtual_mailbox_maps** and **virtual_transport** directives to dovecot. Also, postfix works as SMTP-server for sending messaged from RoundCube.

So, I have mailbox *m1@domain.com* on Google Workspace account and mailbox *m2@domain.com*, defined in my Postfix **virtual_mailbox_maps**

- if I send message m1@domain.com => m1@domain.com, it works fine, Google Works routes it inside of account.
- if I send message m1@domain.com => m2@domain.com, it works fine, Google Works routes it to Postfix, then Postfix routes it to virtual mailbox.
- if I send message m2@domain.com => m2@domain.com, it works fine, Postfix routes it to virtual mailbox.
- if I send message m2@domain.com => m1@domain.com... no surpise, it doesn't work. Postfix tries to route it to virtual mailbox via virtual transport, but there no such mailbox, it is served by Google Workspace.

Is there a way to route some message for virtual domain via smtp transport in Postfix? I cannot find any way to do that, I know only **transport_maps** directive, but Postfix doesn't use it, if domain is in **virtual_mailbox_domains** directive. Maybe there is another way, not very hard :)

The only way I see: create second instance of Postfix, that knows nothing about virtual domains, for sending messages from RoundCube.